# Looking for Regex to replace only the space after three digits

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm creating a web-based phonebook based on the phonebook used by our IP phones. The output I get prints all names with their numbers on a single line. Each number consists of three digits and after those digits I need a new line. The closest I've got is this :

[image]

```
name one 111 name two 222 name three 333 name four 444
```

using `(\d)(\s)`

But this still selects the last digit of the three digits so I can't replace it with a newline.

Anyone that might be able to help me ? My code is written with javascript and JQuery.

Comment: Perhaps, `s.replace(/(\d)\s/g, '$1\n')`.

Comment: You should include your JavaScript code as well.

Comment: `s.replace(/\b(\d{3})\s/g, '$1\n')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
/(\s\d{3})\s/g
```

```js
var str = 'name one 111 name two 222 name three 333 ';

str = str.replace(/(\s\d{3})\s/g, '$1\n');

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

regular expression to break at the other side of the number

```
str = str.replace(/ (?=\d{3})/g, '\n');
```

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: the one of Dowie (the first). Sorry for the late answer. I was offline.

Comment: But they want a line break after the digits, not before.